# PHP adding variable thats inside if statement

Tags: php, if-statement

I dont understand why my code doesn't work....What I am trying to do is have a variable hold a number if a condition is true, and then add that variable to other variables

```
$monthlyCharge = 0.00;

$x = 5;
$y = 10;
$z = 15;

if($y > $x){
$monthlyCharge = number_format($x * (3 / 100),2);
}

$totalAmount = (round($x + $y + $z + $monthlyCharge),2);
```

It looks okay to me, not sure why its not working

Comment: Please define *its not working*. What do you want to happen and what happens? [The error seems to be clear](http://codepad.org/kb8c1KVY): `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' on line 9` (last line).

Comment: it $totalAmount takes $x adds $y adds $z but doesn't add $monthlyCharge

Comment: Need to do some basic debugging!

Comment: You need to (1) show us more code (what are $x, $y, and $z and $chargesArray), and (2) tell us what error or result you're getting.

Comment: ... and you really should accept an answer on some of your 7 questions.

Comment: Make sure that when you ask a question, you add your actual code and not introduce new errors in the code you post. How do you expect anyone to help you? Your code has still syntax errors.

Answer (score 3):

I believe:

```
$totalAmount = round($x + $y + $z + $monthlyCharge),2);
```

should be

```
$totalAmount = round(($x + $y + $z + $monthlyCharge),2);
```

Comment: that wasn't the problem...in ym actual code I had it like that

Comment: So could you update your code to reflect EXACTLY what your PHP code is?

Comment: You modified your code to `$totalAmount = (round($x + $y + $z + $monthlyCharge),2);` which is still incorrect and different than what I suggested.

Answer (score 3):

number_format gives you a string not a number. Just remove it.

http://php.net/manual/de/function.number-format.php

The number_format belongs to the other part, then the brackets make sense as well.